# Scanning BarCode from image Gallery ios 7

Tags: ios7, avfoundation, barcode-scanner, avcapturesession

I want to scan a barcode or QR code image which is in my photo gallery in ios 7. In ios 7 we can use camera to scan a bar code image but I did not find any method to select a Bar code image from UIImagePickerController and scan it. Is there any methods available in AVFoundation Framework ? 
Help me..

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, most of the once perfectly running 32 bit barcode SDKs are broken with 7.1 due to the architecture requirement to support arm64. Zbar is affected, ZXing totally got out of the iOS platform what is left are commercial packages. I tried one of them called manatee it works but it is truncating the first character of the barcode from the output. At the moment your best bet are these commercial SDKs working with IOS 7.1 or go back to 7.0 or 6.1 and use Zbar.

AVfoundation solution put forward by @Stark works well with camera capture (I've tested it with some modifications to recognise PDF417, AztecCodes, and 6 or so 1D barcodes),however the codes in the sample app cannot process existing images from the media library. I searched intensively and the nearest bet is the CoreImage detection which does facial recognition on images, unfortunately there is no barcode detection option yet.

Answer (score -3):

There are many APIs available for barcode scanning:-

- Softek Barcode Reader SDK
- ZBar bar code reader
- shopsavvy
- red laser
- ZXing

If you want to use AVfoundation framework only, here is the link for the tutorial..
http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/

Here is the code which start Reading the barcode

```
 - (BOOL)startReading {
    NSError *error;

    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:captureDevice error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return NO;
    }

    _captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [_captureSession addInput:input];

    AVCaptureMetadataOutput *captureMetadataOutput = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
    [_captureSession addOutput:captureMetadataOutput];

    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue;
    dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatchQueue];
    [captureMetadataOutput setMetadataObjectTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]];

    _videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
    [_videoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    [_videoPreviewLayer setFrame:_viewPreview.layer.bounds];
    [_viewPreview.layer addSublayer:_videoPreviewLayer];

    [_captureSession startRunning];

    return YES;
}
```

and to stop it.

```
-(void)stopReading{
    [_captureSession stopRunning];
    _captureSession = nil;

    [_videoPreviewLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```